# tidyr use glue strings later in function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval, quasiquotes

[Tidy eval now supports glue strings](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/)

So this works great:

```
my_summarise5 <- function(data, mean_var ) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(
      "mean_{{mean_var}}" := mean({{ mean_var }}), 
    ) 
}

mtcars %>% my_summarise5(cyl)
```

But then

```
my_summarise5 <- function(data, mean_var ) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(
      "mean_{{mean_var}}" := mean({{ mean_var }}), 
    "mean_{{mean_var}}_plusone" :=  "mean_{{mean_var}}"+1
    )
}

mtcars %>% my_summarise5(cyl)
```

Throws

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `mean_cyl_plusone`.
x non-numeric argument to binary
```

Would some 'paste' or 'glue' thing in the `"mean_{{mean_var}}_plusone" :=  "mean_{{mean_var}}"+1` part  fix this?

Note this is obviously not a useful case, its a MWE for the syntax. I actually want to define two new columns with different names, one which uses the other ... otherwise I have to repeat and it also gets messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love the tidyverse, but using base R can have a big payoff, by making your code readable and maintainable.

```r
my_summarise5 <- function (data, mean_var) {
  mean_name <- paste0("mean_", mean_var)
  plus_one_name <- paste0(mean_name, "_plus_one")

  data[[mean_name]] <- mean(data[[mean_var]])
  data[[plus_one_name]] <- data[[mean_name]] + 1

  data
}
```

Anybody who knows R can understand the above.

```
tmp <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
my_summarise5(tmp, "a")
##   a mean_a mean_a_plus_one
## 1 1      3               4
## 2 2      3               4
## 3 3      3               4
## 4 4      3               4
## 5 5      3               4
```

If you want to pass a bare symbol as `mean_var`, then just add this line to the start of the function:

```r
mean_var <- as.character(substitute(mean_var))
```

This isn't perfect, because it'll break with deeply nested functions. So you could mix a little tidyverse in by doing (something like) `mean_var <- enquo(mean_var)`. But I still would prefer the simple data manipulation to stuff with `mutate` and `across`.

Answer (score 4):

Use across:

```
my_summarise5 <- function(data, mean_var ) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(
      "mean_{{mean_var}}" := mean({{ mean_var }}),
      across(last_col(), ~.+1, .names = "{col}_plusone")
    )
}

mtcars %>% my_summarise5(cyl) %>% head
```

giving:

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mean_cyl mean_cyl_plusone
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   6.1875           7.1875
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   6.1875           7.1875
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   6.1875           7.1875
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   6.1875           7.1875
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   6.1875           7.1875
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   6.1875           7.1875
```

Comment: And the ".names" is something I forgot too!